# Why is indexing of UTF8 strings discouraged in Julia?

Tags: string, utf-8, julia

The introductory guide to Julia, [Learn Julia in Y Minutes](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/julia/), discourages users from indexing UTF8 strings:

```
# Some strings can be indexed like an array of characters
"This is a string"[1] # => 'T' # Julia indexes from 1
# However, this is will not work well for UTF8 strings,
# so iterating over strings is recommended (map, for loops, etc).
```

Why is iterating over such strings discouraged? What specifically about the structure of this alternate string type makes indexing error prone? Is this a Julia specific pitfall, or does this extend to all languages with UTF8 string support?

Comment: Since UTF-8 is a multi-byte encoding of Unicode, things like indexing into a UTF-8 string, or getting the length (in characters as opposed to code units) are O(n) (where n is the size of the string) operation. If you need to do things like that frequently, you'd be better off using UTF32String, and converting to/from UTF8 as needed.  This isn't a Julia specific pitfall, but some languages like Python 3 can pick the best internal representation for Unicode strings, that are still O(1) for indexing, depending on the string.

Comment: @ScottJones Thanks for the tip. UTF32String (which is similar to `std::wstring` in C++) is really what I need.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because in UTF8 a character is not always encoded in a single byte.

Take for example the german language string `böse` (evil).
The bytes of this string in UTF8 encoding are:

```
0x62 0xC3 0xB6 0x73 0x65
b    ö         s    e
```

As you can see the umlaut `ö` requires 2 bytes.

Now if you directly index this UTF8 encoded string `"böse"[4]` will give you `s`and not `e`.

However, you can use the string as an iterable object in julia:

```th
julia> for c in "böse"
           println(c)
       end
b
ö
s
e
```

And since you've asked, No, direct byte indexing issues with UTF8 strings are not specific to Julia.

Recommendation for further reading:
http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/strings/#unicode-and-utf-8

Comment: you can also iterate using `chr2ind` which converts from byte indices to character indices: `for i in 1:length(s); c = chr2ind(s, i); println(s[c]); end`.

Comment: @amrods you could use the `graphemes` function instead: `collect(graphemes("böse"))` returns `["b", "ö", "s", "e"]`

Comment: Good point http://stackoverflow.com/users/2374329/ismael-venegas-castelló For a lot of use cases, using graphemes is really the best option, look at Swift 2.0's string handling, where graphemes are what you normally work with, not code points or code units.

Answer (score 2):

Just to expand upon Scott Jones' comment, Julia actually also offers fixed-width strings similar to the `std::wstring` from C++, which allows for convenient indexing. They are now in https://github.com/JuliaStrings/LegacyStrings.jl One needs to install the package first with `Pkg.add("LegacyStrings")`.

`UTF32String` would be the best choice for most use cases. To construct an `UTF32String` from a normal string: `s2 = utf32(s)`.