# Julia: How to read in and output characters with diacritics?

Tags: julia, character, ascii, diacritics

Processing ASCII characters beyond the range 1-127 can easily crash Julia.

```
mystring = "A-Za-zÀ-ÿŽž"
for i in 1:length(mystring)
    print(i,":::")
    print(Int(mystring[i]),"::" )
    println(  mystring[i]       )
end
```

gives me

```
1:::65::A
2:::45::-
3:::90::Z
4:::97::a
5:::45::-
6:::122::z
7:::192::À
8:::ERROR: LoadError: StringIndexError("A-Za-zÀ-ÿŽž", 8)
Stacktrace:
 [1] string_index_err(::String, ::Int64) at .\strings\string.jl:12
 [2] getindex_continued(::String, ::Int64, ::UInt32) at .\strings\string.jl:220
 [3] getindex(::String, ::Int64) at .\strings\string.jl:213
 [4] top-level scope at R:\_LV\STZ\Web_admin\Languages\Action\Returning\chars.jl:5
 [5] include(::String) at .\client.jl:457
 [6] top-level scope at REPL[18]:1
```

It crashes *after* outputting the first character outside the normal range, rather than during that output, which is mentioned in the answer to [String Index Error (Julia)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51977406/string-index-error-julia)
If declaring the values in Julia one should declare them as Unicode, but I have these characters in my input.
The manual says that Julia looks at the locale, but is there an "everywhere" locale?

Is there some way to handle input and output of these characters in Julia?

I am working on Windows10, but I can switch to Linux if that works better for this.

Comment: The answers given below are great. This issue is indeed confusing, and I feel the choice made for handling string indexing is not the best. At the time, it might have been hard to make any other choice (due to young language), but changing this in, say, Julia 2.x might be a good big change.

Comment: I belive string indexing was _very_ thoroughly considered, and that it is not generally seen as a mistake in hindsight. What kind of changes do you want to see? Going to 'naive' indexing seems highly unlikely.

Comment: @DNF This isn't a debate for this comment thread. There are pros and cons to choices made about strings. The decisions made were correct, I agree. There is a place to refresh these choices and perhaps make another String type which gives a better interface and protects from some thorny issues. The 'unexpected' exception raised in this question, is one of these issues. Some devs wouldn't mind being oblivious to these (including me most of time).

Comment: So the drop-in answer is that instead of the expected mystring[i] one can use mystring[nextind(mystring, 0, i)].  If that could be aliased by something like mystring[[i]] with a suitable warning about performance, then it would be easier for some of us to understand, although I don't know whether that fits with Julia philosophy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `eachindex` to get a list of valid indices in your string:

```
julia> mystring = "A-Za-zÀ-ÿŽž"
"A-Za-zÀ-ÿŽž"

julia> for i in eachindex(mystring)
           print(i, ":::")
           print(Int(mystring[i]), "::")
           println(mystring[i])
       end
1:::65::A
2:::45::-
3:::90::Z
4:::97::a
5:::45::-
6:::122::z
7:::192::À
9:::45::-
10:::255::ÿ
12:::381::Ž
14:::382::ž
```

Your issue is related to the fact that Julia uses byte-indexing of strings, as is explained [in the Julia Manual](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/strings/#Unicode-and-UTF-8).

For example character `À` takes two bytes, therefore, since its location is 7 the next index is 9 not 8.

In UTF-8 encoding which is used by default by Julia only ASCII characters take one byte, all other characters take 2, 3 or 4 bytes, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Encoding.

For example for `À` you get two bytes:

```
julia> codeunits("À")
2-element Base.CodeUnits{UInt8, String}:
 0xc3
 0x80
```

I have also written a post at https://bkamins.github.io/julialang/2020/08/13/strings.html that tries to explain how byte-indexing vs character-indexing works in Julia.

If you have additional questions please comment.

Answer (score 2):

***String indices** in Julia **refer to** code units (= **bytes** for UTF-8), the fixed-width building blocks that are used to encode arbitrary characters (code points). This means that **not every index** into a String **is necessarily a valid index** for a character. If you index into a string at such an invalid byte index, an error is thrown.*

You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/iterators/#Base.Iterators.enumerate) to get the **value** and the **number of iteration**.

```
mystring = "A-Za-zÀ-ÿŽž"

for (i, x) in enumerate(mystring)
    print(i,":::")
    print(Int(x),"::")
    println(x)
end
#1:::65::A
#2:::45::-
#3:::90::Z
#4:::97::a
#5:::45::-
#6:::122::z
#7:::192::À
#8:::45::-
#9:::255::ÿ
#10:::381::Ž
#11:::382::ž
```

In case you need the **value** and **index of the string in bytes** you can use [`pairs`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.pairs).

```
for (i, x) in pairs(mystring)
    print(i,":::")
    print(Int(x),"::")
    println(x)
end
#1:::65::A
#2:::45::-
#3:::90::Z
#4:::97::a
#5:::45::-
#6:::122::z
#7:::192::À
#9:::45::-
#10:::255::ÿ
#12:::381::Ž
#14:::382::ž
```

Comment: What is the difference between the two? Is the second one just a shorthand for the first, or is their more going on?

Comment: The first one gives you the *number of iteration* the second one the *index of the string in bytes*. I have edited the answer to point on the difference.

Answer (score 1):

In preparation for de-minimising my MCVE for what I want to do, which involves advancing the string position not just in a for-all loop, I used the information in the post written by Bogumił Kamiński, to come up with this:

```
mystring = "A-Za-zÀ-ÿŽž"
for i in 1:length(mystring)
    print(i,":::")
    mychar = mystring[nextind(mystring, 0, i)]
    print(Int(mychar), "::")
    println(  mychar )
end
```